# Insert or print a column name inside a data table call

Tags: r, data.table

I have a rather simple problem as it seems, which I cannot solve myself however.

Can I somehow insert or print a column name within a data table call? I have something like this in mind:

```
col_names = c("column1","column2")
for (col in col_names){
        datatable$col ...
}
```

or

```
col_names = c("column1","column2")
for (col in col_names){
        datatable[,col] ...
}
```

What I eventually would like to do is transform the variables of certain columns into ordered factors. Since there are many columns, I'm looking for a neater way as an alternative of just coding the same line 20 times with the only difference being the column name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah, I'm not just trying to print them. I just edited my question to add more detail. Sorry for the insufficient specification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print the just the column name or the entire column within the datatable?

You could try something like this

```
col_names = c("column1","column2")
for (i in seq_along(col_names)){
        print(datatable[col_names[[i]]])
}
```

Or if you just want the names printed.

```
col_names = c("column1","column2")
for (i in seq_along(col_names)){
        print(col_names[[i]])
}
```

Also, you might want to check out the iteration chapter in [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Sorry, I might need to specify this in my question. But no, I actually want to perform transformations on the single columns and not just print them.

Comment: Oh! Well then I would absolutely use tidyverse and purr functions for that. You can use ```map()``` from purr to perform functions across multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can try `lapply` with `SDcols` to apply a function over `col_names`. You can try something like this :=

```
library(data.table)
datatable[, (col_names) := lapply(.SD, function(x) factor(x, ordered =  TRUE)), 
             .SDcols = col_names]
```

Here we apply `factor(x, ordered =  TRUE)` to each column in `col_names` where `x` is each individual column name.